# Why chained variables not involved anymore in the taskassigning example solution from Optaplanner 8.17?

Tags: optaplanner

From OptaPlanner 8.17, it seems that the code of task assigning example project has been refactored a lot. I didn't succeed in finding in the release notes nor on Github any comment about these changes.

In particular, the implementation of the problem to solve doesn't involve chained variables anymore since this version. Could someone from the OptaPlanner team explain why ? I'm also a bit confuse because the [latest version of the documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.28.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#taskAssigningDomainModel) related to this example project is still referencing the previous deleted classes from version before 8.17 (eg.
org/optaplanner/examples/taskassigning/domain/TaskOrEmployee.java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using `@PlanningListVariable`, an new (experimental) alternative to chained planning variables, which is far easier to understand and maintain.

Documentation for this new feature hasn't been written yet. We're finishing up the `ListVariableListener` interface and then the documantation will be updated to cover `@PlanningListVariable` too. At that time, it will be ready for announcement.

Unlike a normal feature, this big, complex feature took more than a year to bake. That's why it's been delivered in portions. One could argue the task assignment example shouldn't have escaped the feature branch, but it was proving extremely expensive to not merge the stable feature branches in sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thanks a lot Geoffrey for your input! Does it mean that this feature shouldn't be used right now for production ? Even if it is indeed far easier to understand but experimental ? Anyway I definitively look forward to the documentation of this new feature as well as the ListVariableListener interface.

Comment: You're welcome. I would wait a bit longer to start using it in production. It would be a shame if your users need a new feature tomorrow that requires you to use a ListVariableListener and you'd have to change your entire model back to chained.